# What is the difference between math.remainder() and math.fmod() in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I could not understand the difference between `math.fmod()` and `math.remainder()` functions in the `math` module of Python3. Please someone help me out.

Comment: Just type `help(math.fmod)` and `help(math.remainder)` in any Python interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around with some numbers may help:

```
from math import remainder, fmod

# in case x is a multiple of y
remainder(20, 4)    # 0.0
fmod(20, 4)         # 0.0

# in any other case
remainder(20, 3)    # -1.0
fmod(20, 3)         # 2.0
```

So what we see here is that the remainder, as stated in the docs, returns the difference between x and the closest integer multiple of y. As 20 lies between 18 and 21 (the 6- and 7-multiples of 3), it chooses whichever is closer to x. In this case it is 21, so the difference between x and 21 is `-1.0`.

In contrast, fmod returns the result of `20 mod 3`, which is `2.0`. I explicitly do not use the `%` operator, as the docs state that the result may differ.